# Retrieve group from symbian using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I got the Contact List of symbian but not getting the group. for getting the contactlist i have coded

```
PIM pim;

pim=PIM.getInstance();

ContactList clist=null;

clist=(ContactList)pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);

Contact c=null;

Enumeration contacts=clist.items();

while(contacts.hasMoreElements()){
                c=(Contact)contacts.nextElement();
...
...
}
```

now how to get the group and retrieve group members ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, groups should be implemented using JSR-75 Categories.

Try using:

`PIMList.getCategories()`
`PIMList.itemsByCategory()`
`PIMItem.getCategories()`

Comment: how to get the group id like we are getting contact id by contact.uid

Comment: No such thing as Group Id in JSR-75, I'm afraid. Categories are just String.